# How to convert byte array to long without using java.nio?

Tags: java, networking, arrays, long-integer, checksum

I am implementing a reliable data transfer protocol. I need to pass the checksum which is long value to a receiver. I am not allowed to use java.nio.

I know how to convert long to byte array as show below:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeLong(someLong);
dos.close();
byte[] longBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

But how do I convert byte array to long without using java.nio?

Comment: Show your work so we can have understanding for the same

Comment: Start by converting a long to 8 bytes and back, then doing it for a whole array will be easy.

Comment: I edited the question as above. I am mainly concerned with how to convert a byte array into long.

Comment: @uohzxela You can't do that without knowing how exactly the other conversion was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(longBytes);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);
    someLong = dis.readLong();
```

Comment: @uohzxela is the byte array guaranteed to be of length <= 8?

Comment: Yes it should be size 8.